# Why does os.getcwd() return different values in vs code and terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a simple python3.7 code like this :

```
import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = os.getcwd()
    print(c)
```

This code path is `~/PyStudy/OsTest/test.py`

When I ran it in VS Code and Terminal, different results appeared.

- in Terminal, it returned: `~/PyStudy/OsTest`
- in VS Code, it returned: `~/PyStudy` without `/OsTest`.

I used Code Runner in VS Code to run python code.

I don't know why, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are running in different directories.

Apparently you started VS Code in the parent directory, and it simply keeps on running there until you terminate it.

Also apparently, you ran the script from the terminal by first doing a `cd` into this directory. There's no need to do that, though. Try

```
( cd /; python3 ~/PyStudy/OsTest/test.py )
```

at the Terminal prompt.

Generally speaking, the current working directory of a process is a convenience mechanism. By using relative paths, you can write shorter file names; but in most situations, you can use an absolute file name instead, from a process running in any directory.

Answer (score 0):

If it's returning different values, you can be sure it's returning the correct values. The difference must be in the way you're running the program. Vs code probably sets its working directory to something different than what you were doing when running from a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The entry points for execution are different for both. That is why it is happening.